# Simple Nef_Polyhedron_3 query

Tags: cgal

I tried following the example in the CGAL module on 3D Boolean Operations on Nef Polyhedra. In the first example

```
Nef_polyhedron N0(Nef_polyhedron::EMPTY);
Nef_polyhedron N1(Nef_polyhedron::COMPLETE);
CGAL_assertion (N0 == N1.complement());
```

the code runs fine, since the assertion is true.

However, I tried running a slightly different version

```
 Nef_polyhedron N0(Nef_polyhedron::EMPTY);
 Nef_polyhedron N1(Nef_polyhedron::COMPLETE);
 CGAL_assertion (N0 == N1);
```

And yet there is no assertion error that is caught.

Is there some concept mistake that I am having? Or is empty and complete polyhedron both referring to the same thing?

Comment: Do you compile in release or debug mode? More particularly, is `NDEBUG` or `CGAL_NDEBUG` defined?

Comment: Yes, the CGAL_assertion definitely works. 
I tried other types of Nef_polyhedron assertion checks, it works fine. 

its just the complete and empty seems to be equal, which bothers me slightly, as I am not sure if i am doing it correctly.

Comment: This is a bug! I've submitted a [PR](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/2156) for that issue.